# Change width of .ui-title inside data-role="header"

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I am working on a website with Jquery Mobile. My title is aligned center of the menu as in the image above:

[image: Title of page aligned center with green border]

My CSS for the green border is:

```
.ui-title 
{
    border: 2px solid lime;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" class="menu">
    <a href="#" data-icon="home" data-theme="a">Home</a>
    <h1>Title</h1>
</div>
```

What I want is the title to span full width (relative to the current width of the window), but still be centered, as the pink lines in following image:

[image: Title of page aligned center with green border and pink lines describing the target width]

Any idea how to achieve this without breaking the Jquery Mobile layout (such as device-width for different target devices)?

**Solution:**

```
margin-right: 1% !important;
margin-left: 1% !important;
```

It seems to work in my case (even though the title gets behind the button if the window is small enough).

**Update:**

No work-around with surrounding div or changing CSS styles, such as margins, solved the issue with header getting too wide on some devices. I guess that's why the title is so small, to fit all devices properly. I had no time to test this for hours, so I eventually gave up and went back to the default layout, and just made sure the title was narrow enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this css and set your left and right percentage (change 10% to any other number)

```
.ui-title {
    margin: 0.6em 10% 0.8em !important;
}
```

in case you want different values on different sides use this css:

```
.ui-title {
    margin: 0.6em 10% 0.8em 5% !important;
}
```

Also if possible give every header an id because mentioned css will change every element using .ui-title class.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/QP9qm/2/

Comment: Any reason to use `!important`?

Comment: To override a original setting: margin: 0.6em 30% 0.8em !important;

Comment: Thank you @Gajotres, you led me in the right direction with margin together with `!important`. I have updated my question with a solution based on your answer.

Comment: difference in percentage on left vs right margin still makes the title slide under the title if the window is small enough. Not a big problem really, but would be nice with a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Set the header or ui-title to:

```
 .post .ui-header .ui-title {
  margin:0;
  width:100%;

  }
```

It should work that way.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you expect a workaround without div or css? And what's wrong with that?

---

### Option 1: Copy what they do on JqueryMobile.com

Anyway this is how they do it on the actual jQuery Mobile site (1.4.2). I can't comment on what the state of jQuery mobile was back in Jan 2013.

```
<div data-role="header" class="jqm-header">
    <h2><a href="../" title="jQuery Mobile Demos home"><img src="../_assets/img/jquery-logo.png" alt="jQuery Mobile"></a></h2>
    <p><span class="jqm-version"></span> Demos</p>
    <a href="#" class="jqm-navmenu-link ui-btn ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all ui-icon-bars ui-nodisc-icon ui-alt-icon ui-btn-left">Menu</a>
    <a href="#" class="jqm-search-link ui-btn ui-btn-icon-notext ui-corner-all ui-icon-search ui-nodisc-icon ui-alt-icon ui-btn-right">Search</a>
</div>
```

The default stylesheet for the .ui-title (which is what h2 gets auto-enhanced to) is the following.
You'll see that here it is `margin: 0 30%` that's causing you the problem.

```
ui-header .ui-title, .ui-footer .ui-title 
{
   font-size: 1em;
   min-height: 1.1em;
   text-align: center;
   display: block;
   margin: 0 30%;
   padding: .7em 0;
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   overflow: hidden;
   white-space: nowrap;
   outline: 0!important;
}
```

In their override stylesheet

```
.jqm-demos .jqm-header h2 
{
   padding: .4em 0 .1em;
   margin: 0 3em;
}
```

Adding this override was enough to get my logo centered.

(there may be an alternative way to do this using `data-enhance='false'` but that didn't im

### Option 2: Disable auto-enhancement

You can disable auto enhancement to prevent the `ui-title` class being applied in the first place and breaking your css. There's other side effects, like other buttons aren't configured properly and I don't recommend this way but it's good to know about this feature maybe for elsewhere.

First you must set

```
$.mobile.ignoreContentEnabled = true;
```

Note: You must do this on `mobileinit` which must be configured BEFORE you load jQueryMobile. Like this or however you want to do it.

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).on('mobileinit', function () {
        alert("ignoreContentEnabled initial value = " +$.mobile.ignoreContentEnabled);
        $.mobile.ignoreContentEnabled = true;
    });
</script>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.js"></script>
```

Then update the header to be

```
<div data-role="header" id="defenderHeader" data-enhance="false">
```

Nothing within it will be auto-enhanced. Unfortunately this doesn't work if you put it on the `<h2>` which is what I originally wanted to do. You can explore this option further but I think option 1 is best and easiest.

See also: http://api.jquerymobile.com/global-config/

Comment: Thank you for sharing your options. As a side note, I suspect that the real reason why they have this margin in Jquery Mobile is because otherwise the layout will break in certain low-res devices. To change the margin will sure solve the problem on many devices, but it is risky if not tested extensively.